# Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio & RCX Support?

Tags: rcx

What is the last version of the Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio that supports the RCX?

The Wikipedia link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Robotics_Developer_Studio) indicates RCX was dropped in the "latest" version but doesn't indicate what version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Robotics Developer Studio, but the phrase indicating that support was dropped in the latest version was [added in July 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Microsoft_Robotics_Developer_Studio&diff=next&oldid=228652195), so you'll need to go back to version 1.5 in order to have RCX support.